# Creating Currency Formatter Javascript Input

Tags: javascript, html

I have searched all around, and not been able to find the answer I have been looking for. I have found one answer that was achieved with AngularJS, but I'm not sure how to implement that. I have created a javascript function that formats an input field while a user is typing. It will be used for entering a dollar amount. It functions as follows: 
1) User types 1: `.1` -Not ideal, would like it to be 0.01, but it's working for most part
2) User types 2: `.12`
3) User types 5: `1.25`
I have messed around and achieved the desired outcome through this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function format_num(id) {
    var number = document.getElementById(id).value;
    number = number.replace(".","");
    number = number.replace(/\D/g, "");

    if (number.length == 0) {
     number = ""
     } else { 

        if (number.length <2) {
            number = [".", number].join('');
        } else {
            number = [number.slice(0, (number.length-2)), number.slice(number.length-2)].join('.');
        }
    }
        document.getElementById(id).value = number;
}
</script>
```

And it is called here: 
`<input class="number" name="balance" id="balance" value="" onkeyup="format_num(id)" />`
I tried declaring my input field as type"number" but I found that it worked in Chrome, but not Safari. The only downside of this is the lack of a "0.xx" when the number is less than 3 digits long (i.e.: 0.01 or 0.10). Is this code safe for use? Thanks!

Comment: Just divide the input number by 100 and convert it to string?

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I didn't think of this! My only issue now is that if it it's either `0.00` or `0.01` and I press delete, it goes to 0. Is there anyway to fix this? Thanks again!

Comment: You could add an if case to check if value is `0` then display `0.00` :) - sometimes the simplest solutions are the most elegant!

Comment: @Alex I was trying something like that but made it more complex than I should; you're totally right though! Does this look right? Thanks again! `number = parseFloat(number)
   number = number/100
   if (parseFloat(number) == 0) {
      number = "0.00"
   }`

Comment: Looks good to me Josh, glad I could help :)

Comment: That function makes editing an existing value rather painful. And doesn't prevent the user pasting in a value in some other format...

Comment: @nnnnnn when I paste in a value, that contains characters, it deletes the letters. Is there a better way to go about with this? I am not very experienced with web design, thanks!

Comment: If you paste using the mouse it won't trigger your key event handler. If you do a validation on the change event too that'll cover everything.